# Comparing The Index and Values of Two Arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I created 4 arrays to store employee-data (ID, Name, Age, Salary).

```
String[] empID = new String[arrayLength];
String[] empName = new String[arrayLength];
int[] empAge = new int[arrayLength];
double[] empPay = new double[arraylength];
```

I sorted the salary arrays in ascending order.

```
Arrays.sort(empPay);
```

I want the index of the elements in the sorted array (empPay) against the original array (tempPay) similar to the code below.

```
        double[] price = {12,4,65.89,33.5,24,90};
        double[] pr = {4,12,24,33.5,65.89,90};
        int[] pos = new int[6];
        int prCount = 0;
        do {
            for (int i=0;i<price.length;i++) {
                if (pr[prCount] == price[i]) {
                    pos[prCount] = i;
                    prCount++;
                }
            }
        } while (prCount<pr.length);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pos));
```

When I apply this logic to my code, I get an "IndexOutOfBoundException"

```
...
inPay = scanner.nextDouble();
for (...) {
  empPay[count] = inPay;
  tempPay[count] = inPay;
}
Arrays.sort(empPay);
int[] index = new int[arrayLength];
int listCount = 0;
do {
  for (int j=0;j<tempPay.length;j++) {
    if (empPay[listCount] == tempPay[j]) {
      index[listCount] = j;
      listCount++;
    }
  }
} while (listCount<empPay.length);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(index));
```

Why does the logic work in the first code and not the second. I want to display all employee information properly aligned.
Please, Kindly avoid objects or collections or other sophisticated approach to the problem. I teach Grade 9 kids.

Comment: No kid deserves parallel arrays.

Comment: *`"Please, Kindly avoid objects"`* - You consider object to be a complicated notion and instead want them to maintain a series of arrays bounded one to another through shared indices. It doesn't seem to be easier, but only facilitates developing bad habits.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko Thank you for your response. I quite agree with you. It's frustrating. But I have to follow the curriculum.

Comment: Your way is quite complex. what I can suggest is to use `objects` if you can't use them use `double array`s

Comment: @ManeeshaIndrachapa Thank you for your response. Do you mean two-dimensional array.

Comment: yeah two-dimentional array

Comment: Thanks everyone ... I solved it with a try catch block